# 301 Redirect from http to https and new page name

Tags: .htaccess, seo

I have a site that is going from a non secure HTML/PHP site to a secure Wordpress site.  All pages are changing.  Also going from www to non-www.

So as an example

http://www.sitename.com/contact.php

will become

https://sitename.com/contact-us/

I know how to do a typical redirect in .htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 /oldpage.html http://www.example.com/newpage.html
```

But I'm not sure how to do this when both the page location and the HTTP/HTTPS is changing as well as the www going away.  The site ranks pretty well and I don't want to lose any of that.

I've researched but can't find an example of doing both at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do using rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^contact\.php$ https://%1/contact-us/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

Since your page names are different you will need multiple rules like this.

Make sure to keep these rules above all other rules.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^contact\.php$ https://example.com/contact-us [NC,L,R=301,NE]
```

The rule above rewrites the following requests :

- http://www.example.com/contact.php

or

- http://example.com/contact.php
  or
- https://www.example.com/contact.php

to

- https://example.com/contact-us

Comment: If you're using `RewriteRule ^contact\.php$ https://example.com/contact-us [NC,L,R=301,NE]` then both `RewriteCond` are redundant and can be left out.

Comment: what is the [HTTPS] off for?  I'm wondering if that will mess with Wordpress